# D3 adding to multiple divs (Data Binding JSON)

Tags: json, d3.js, data-binding

I'm relatively new to D3 and had a question about data-binding. I've used angular.js, so I'm used to two way data binding... but I was wondering how it gets done on D3.

I'm trying to add different elements of my json data to different divs.

So in this instance: member names is names, types in types, categories in categories.

In the future was going to add a click event to the grid, so when you click a member name it shows more information.

I know for angular you can just use ng-repeat and interpolate the data. But not sure how this is achieved in d3.

Any help would be cool :-)

(The code below doesn't work. I guess you can't label multiple variables)

```
    <div id="container" class="AM-grid">

            <div class="AM-cell AM-cell-3">
                    <h2 id="names" class="AM-members-text names"></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="AM-cell AM-cell-2">
                    <h2 id="type" class="AM-members-text type"></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="AM-cell AM-cell-3">
                    <h2 id="category" class="AM-members-text category"></h2>
            </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script>

var boxtext = document.getElementById('textarea');
var jsonbox = JSON.parse(boxtext.innerHTML);


var dataElms = d3.select('#container')
        .data(jsonbox)

var na = dataElms.select("#names")
        na.data(jsonbox.member).enter().append('h2')
            .text(function(d){
                return d.display
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... was thinking about it the wrong way

should repeat the elements then attach styles

```
var dataElms = d3.select('#container').selectAll('.repeat');
var repeat = dataElms.selectAll('div')
    .data(jsonbox.member)
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .classed('AM-grid members', true)
    .on('click', function(d,i) {
        var activeClass = "active";
    var alreadyIsActive = d3.select(this).classed(activeClass);
        d3.select(this).classed(activeClass, !alreadyIsActive);
        })
    .html(function(d) {
        return "<div class='AM-cell AM-cell-3'>" + "<h2 class='AM-members-subheader'>" + d.display + "</h2></div>" +
                     "<div class='AM-cell AM-cell-3'>" + "<h2 class='AM-members-subheader'>" + d.member_type + "</h2></div>" +
                     "<div class='AM-cell AM-cell-3'>" + "<h2 class='AM-members-subheader'>" + d.category + "</h2></div>" +
                     "<div class='AM-cell AM-cell-2'>" + "<h2 class='AM-members-subheader'>" + d.hash + "</h2></div>"
    });
```